# How to sort elements and position with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make the elements animate from top to bottom regardless of which item is clicked first, or the order to which the buttons are clicked?

For example, an output like (below), but still maintains the entrance animation and closing functionalities of the snippet.

1. `Fourth`
2. `Second`
3. `First`
4. `Third`

**JQuery ([FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kfnyn908/9/)):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //ENTRANCE
  $("#first").css("top", -1000);
  $("#1st").on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#first").animate({
      top: 10
    }, 400);
  }, 200);
    });

  $("#second").css("top", -1000);
  $("#2nd").on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#second").animate({
      top: 10 + 45 + 15
    }, 400);
  }, 400);
    });

  $("#third").css("top", -1000);
  $("#3rd").on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#third").animate({
      top: 10 + 45 + 45 + 30
    }, 400);
  }, 600);
});

  $("#four").css("top", -1000);
  $("#4th").on('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#four").animate({
      top: 10 + 45 + 45 + 45 + 45
    }, 400);
  }, 800);
});
  //EXIT
  var elements = $('.menu');
  elements.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    var nextEleemnts = $(this).nextAll('.menu');
    for (var i = 0; i < nextEleemnts.length; i++) {
      var topPos = $(nextEleemnts[i]).position().top - 60;
      $(nextEleemnts[i]).animate({
        top: topPos
      }, 400);
    }
  });
  $('#four').on('click', function() {
    window.location.reload();
  });

});
```

Comment: so you want the items to be shown in the order they are clicked, and not in the fixed position they are in now?

Comment: Yes sir, that is my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather then positioning the items absolute, I would add them to an absolute positioned div and keep them in flow there. This way they will automatically stay in the order they are added. You just have to keep them in some hidden library on load, and move them to the target area on click.

In stead of trying to explain (in my pour english), I'll let the code speak for itself: https://jsfiddle.net/kfnyn908/10/

HTML:

```
<div id="library">
  <div id="first" class='menu'>
    First Div
  </div>

  <div id="second" class='menu'>
    Second Div
  </div>

  <div id="third" class='menu'>
    Third Div
  </div>

  <div id="four" class='menu'>
    Reset
  </div>
</div>


<div id="target-area">

</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <button id="1st" data-target="first">Open 1st</button>
  <button id="2nd" data-target="second">Open 2nd</button>
  <button id="3rd" data-target="third">Open 3rd</button>
  <button id="4th" data-target="four">Open 4th</button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var $library = $('#library');
var $target = $('#target-area');
var $buttons = $('#buttons button');

$buttons.on('click', function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var id = $button.data('target');

  $itemToAdd = $library.find('#' + id);
  if ($itemToAdd.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  var top = -($target.height() + $target.offset().top);
  $itemToAdd
    .appendTo($target)
    .css({
      top: top - $itemToAdd.height()
    })
    .animate({
      top: 0
    });
});

$target.on('click', '.menu', function() {
  var $itemToRemove = $(this);

  if ($itemToRemove.attr('id') == 'four') {
    window.location.reload();
    return;
  }

  $itemToRemove.animate({
    top: -($itemToRemove.offset().top + $itemToRemove.height())
  }, function() {
    $itemToRemove.appendTo($library);
  });
})
```

Note that this approach does not make any assumptions about the positions or dimensions of either the target area or the items. Their properties can be changed as desired in your css and things will keep working. The top position for the animation is calculated when needed (in stead of just going for -1000 and assuming that is safe) so the animations should be 'cleaner' as well. Also you can add as many items as you want without having to change the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you a rough logic. Let me know if you need more info.
Have a global click counter and increase it on every click. Add a condition on the counter e.g. if (count == 1) which will decide the position for animation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure i know what your asking for. I have rewritten the jQuery to make things easier. I have split it into functions that will use the class of the HTML element to identify which object to bring in.

HTML now looks like this

```
<div id="first" class='menu item-1'>
    First Div
</div>

<div id="second" class='menu item-2'>
    Second Div
</div>

<div id="third" class='menu item-3'>
    Third Div
</div>

<div id="four" class='menu item-4'>
    Reset
</div>

<button data-div="1" id="1">Open 1st</button>
<button data-div="2" id="2">Open 2nd</button>
<button data-div="3" id="3">Open 3rd</button>
<button data-div="4" id="4">Open 4th</button>
```

Styles are the same but the new jQuery is as follows

```
// Element count
count = 0;

// Init
function init(){
    $(".menu").css("top", -1000);
}

// Bring element onto page
function bring_in_element(el){
    $(".item-" + el).css('z-index', count)
    $(".item-" + el).data('order',count)
    o = $(".item-" + el).data('order');
    $(".item-" + el).animate({ 'top': 10 + (70 * parseInt(o)) }, 400);
    count++;
}

// Remove element from page
function take_out_element(el,b){
    count--;
    el.css("top", -1000);
    $('button#' + b).removeClass('active');
    var elements = $('.menu');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ($(elements[i]).data('order') > el.data('order')) {
            $(elements[i]).animate({ top: '-=70px' }, 400);
            $(elements[i]).data('order',parseInt($(elements[i]).data('order') - 1))
        }
    }
}

$('button').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        bring_in_element($(this).data('div'))
        $(this).addClass('active')
    }
})

$('.menu').click(function(){
    take_out_element($(this),$(this).attr('class').split('').pop())
})

init(); // Init
```

Live working example can be found here

http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/43f9d33820a917df58a54ad16d05bbf9/

The benefit of this is that you don't have to keep repeating these lines every time you want a new element:

```
 $("#four").css("top", -1000);
 $("#4th").on('click', function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
         $("#four").animate({
             top: 10 + 45 + 45 + 45 + 45
         }, 400);
     }, 800);
 }
```

Comment: This works but the exit animations are not included or functional.

Comment: There wasn't any exit animations on the jsfiddle you linked to. Any exit animations need to be added to the take_out_element() function

Comment: @JamieCoulter Please click on one of the buttons, then click on the output to see the exit animation. thanks

Comment: Refresh perhaps, once an item at the top is clicked, it toggles and the element below takes its position.

Comment: I've refreshed a few times and no luck. However i think this is what you are after http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/43f9d33820a917df58a54ad16d05bbf9/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this one does what you described:

https://jsfiddle.net/1fh19usz/15/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This map may be easily eliminated by using HTML custom attributes like data-menu="1st" on div#first etc..
    var btns2items_map = {
        '1st': '#first',
        '2nd': '#second',
        '3rd': '#third',
        '4th': '#fourth'
    };
    //ENTRANCE
    var menuAnimate = initMenuAnimate();
    $('div.menu').css('top', -1000);
    $('button').click(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var menu_id = btns2items_map[self.attr('id')];
        if (menu_id !== undefined) {
            menuAnimate(menu_id);      
        }
    });
    //EXIT
    var elements = $('.menu');
    elements.click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.toggle();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
            if ($(elements[i]).attr('data-order') > self.attr('data-order')) {
                var top_pos = $(elements[i]).position().top - 60;
                $(elements[i]).animate({ top: top_pos }, 400);
            }
        }
    });
    $('#fourth').on('click', function() {
        window.location.reload();
    });
});

function initMenuAnimate() {
    var count = 0;
    return function (menu_item_id) {
        ++count;
        var menu_item = $(menu_item_id);
        menu_item.attr('data-order', count);
        setTimeout(function() {
            menu_item.animate({ top: count * 60 + 10 }, 400);
        }, count * 200);
    }
}
```

Please tell if the code isn't understandable.